# Why we need Big-M method in simplex method?

Tags: convex-optimization, simplex, operations-research

In simplex method, to get the initial feasible solution. We often use Big-M method. My question is can we simply use elementary row transformation to get basis fesible solution instead introduce extra variables?

Answer (score 1):

In the primal simplex method, you want an initial basic feasible solution that is feasible with respect to both the equation constraints $Ax=b$ and to lower/upper bound constraints $l \le x \le u$.  Conventional row operations can easily help you find a nonsingular subset of the columns of $A$ (a basis matrix, $B$), but this wouldn't help you in finding a basic solution that is feasible with respect to the bounds constraints $l \le x \le u$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As my understanding, we have the standard constrain, i.e. $Ax=b,x\ge0$. If we have this standard form, can we use the row operations to get the basic solution as well?

Comment: You'll have the same problem with the less general nonnegativity constraints.